# Spring Loaded , Eclipse and Tomcat integration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Spring loaded can dynamically reload class files in a running web application.
But it can't reload jar files.

Now, I have a project where the Web part includes many other service projects as jar files. All are eclipse based and in the same workspace.

My question is, since we cant reload jars at runtime using spring loaded, can we configure eclipse web project in such a way that
the class files from the service projects are directly copied to my WEB-INF/classes. (I dont want to have jar's of the service projects).

Also do I need to enable the "build automatically" in eclipse to get my changes reflected.

I was able to configure spring-loaded in netbeans with the compile on save option.